# Search validation regex not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to validate my textbox with a regex. The textbox's value should be like this – "/*word*/Search" – i.e. forward slash, then any word, then forward slash again, then the fixed word "Search".

Here is an example input:

```
/admin/Search
```

I tried the following pattern, but it's not matching:

```
[/\/][\w][/\/][\Search]
```

What is wrong in this pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
\/\w+\/Search
```

- `\/` – no real need for a character class (i.e. opened by `[` and closed by `]`) to match a slash...when you can just match the slash  (Note that `\/` presumes you are [using a regex literal rather than constructing a `RegExp` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression): for the latter `/` would do the trick.)
- `\w+` – one or more word characters (similarly with no need for a character class)
- `\/` – the closing slash (same as at the outset)
- `Search` – the fixed word `Search` that you expect following the closing slash (also with no need for a character class)

You can try the updated pattern against the sample textbox input you provided in a [regex fiddle](http://fiddle.re/e8dh1).

**(Nitpicky) Caveat:**

You **may** want to tighten up the *word* subpattern (i.e. `\w+`) because `\w`...

> Matches any alphanumeric character including the underscore. Equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_].

...[according to MDN's JavaScript regular expressions reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters).  At least be conscious that it matches digits and underscore.

**If** you do want to tighten it up, **then** you have an occasion for a character class – for example:

- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` – like `\w+` except that it will not match underscores
- `[A-Za-z]+` – like `\w+` except that it will not match digits *or* underscores

Comment: There are no spaces just a url like /admin/Search .PLease edit it if u work for any space.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, and thanks for the clarification: I updated my answer and the related fiddle accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Since everyone seems to ignore your actual question, what's wrong with your regex is this:

1. character classes `[...]`. This makes `[\Search]` match *a single character* out of `\Search`, *not* the literal word `Search`.
2. for some reason you wrote `/\/` when you actually just want to match a single forward slash `/`.
3. You want to match multiple characters, so you have to change `\w` to `\w+`.

Result:

```
/\w+/Search
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the expresion you are looking for:

```
\\[\w]*\\Search
```

Comment: I want something like this /adminPanel/Search.

Comment: Where is '/'  . Your are taking \